# Aliasing physical memory on Windows

Tags: windows, database-design, shared-memory, virtual-memory

I have two threads and a large dataset. Thread R is continuosly reading from the dataset and presenting the user with a view of the data. Thread W is continuously receiving remote data, performing some work on it and publishing it to the dataset.

Thread R needs to control the granularity at which it receives consistent views of the dataset. One solution is double buffering; W writes to one copy while R reads from another, and when R is ready for an update, either W's copy is atomically copied to R (prohibitive, since the dataset is large and mostly unchanged) or they atomically swap copies and W brings R's old copy up to date by reapplying the incremental changes since the last swap (annoying to keep track of these, and annoying that all deltas have to be processed twice).

What I'd like to do is the following:

- both threads independently reserve virtual read only memory ranges, and both ranges get mapped to the same physical set of pages
- thread W installs an exception handler that traps writes to read only pages, grabs a new physical block, maps it readwrite then lets the write get reattempted
- when R wants an update, atomically (any physical pages in R's view that W has replaced are freed (or returned to a pool), and then those virtual memory addresses get backed with W's new physical pages, then W marks its entire range readonly again).

This avoids extra memory copies, the need to track and reapply deltas etc.

However, AFAICT while Windows does permit the creation of shared memory regions (and even automatic copy-on-write memory regions), it seems to go out of its way to make it impossible to explicitly map physical pages in any way that can be used by W to publish a new view to R.

Is there anything I am missing? - is it possible to implement something like this, a publishing step achieved purely by altering page mappings, without a memory copy?

Comment: Reading all the docs I can find, all the references to COW are in the context of the thing doing the writing creating a private copy for itself by writing through the COW mapping. My mental model of how that worked internally was through something like the exception mechanism in my question, and I'd been assuming that if you asked for rw protection for a range of addresses that's what you'd really get regardless of what other mappings existed, and in that world there is no way to implement a reader-snapshot-via-COW behaviour since the writer's writes aren't trapped; are my assumptions wrong?

Comment: It might be possible to do this with AWE combined with VirtualProtect().  Failing that, it might be possible from a device driver.  But isn't the copy-on-write going to involve at least as much memory copying as the atomic-swap-and-correct approach?  Either way, each block that is written to gets copied once.

Comment: No, AWE won't work: "Physical pages cannot be simultaneously mapped at more than one virtual address."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible to do something close to what you're asking for with a little bit of trickery.

I'll describe what I think is the simplest and most efficient, but least flexible approach first, and call it **approach A**.  To use this approach the data must be arranged in blocks and each block must be contained entirely within a single page:

- Create a read/write view for W and a copy-on-write view for R, using the same file mapping object.
- Whenever W wants to modify a data block, it first performs a dummy write to the corresponding block in the copy-on-write view.

  *NB: I believe that writing to a page will cause the copy-on-write even if the write does not actually change the contents, but to be safe I would recommend avoiding that assumption, which you can do by including a dummy byte in each data block, i.e., one which R will ignore.  W can then increment the dummy byte to ensure that the corresponding page is copied.*
- To synchronize, discard the existing copy-on-write view and create a new one.

I would expect the overhead of the unnecessary dummy writes to be negligible, but aligning the blocks so that they do not overlap page boundaries may be inconvenient.

If so, **approach B** is the same as approach A except that there are multiple dummy bytes, placed at intervals ensuring that each page overlapping the block contains at least one dummy byte.  This increases the overhead for the dummy writes but I would not expect it to be excessive.

However, it might be awkward for W to make these dummy writes explicitly every time it needs to make a change, e.g., if the data is not in fact arranged in blocks, or if having multiple dummy bytes inside each block would be inconvenient.  Therefore, we should consider **approach C**:

- Create both a read-only and a read-write view for W, as well as the copy-on-write view for R.  Have W use the read-only view to read data but the read-write view to write it.
- Use VirtualProtect and PAGE_GUARD to guard all pages in the read-write view.
- When a guard page fault is triggered, have an exception handler make a dummy write to the corresponding page in the copy-on-write view.  A vectored exception handler looks to me like the cleanest option.

  *NB: my research suggests, not very definitively, that this will work despite the fact that it involves deliberately invoking a page fault inside a page fault handler.  It should be supported, since there is no reasonable way for any exception handler to ensure that it does not reference data that is paged out, but since I have not found an explicit statement to that effect some experimentation is advised.*

Approach C is likely to be less efficient than A or B because it requires processing an additional page fault exception, with a corresponding additional round trip to kernel mode and back.  I am also unsure of the page table overhead involved in tracking the guard pages.  However, it is likely to be more convenient, because eliminating the dummy writes from the processing code reduces the extent to which that code needs to be aware of the buffering.

The final variant avoids the need for the processing code to be aware of the buffering *at all* by using a single view regardless of whether W is reading or writing.  **Approach D** is as follows:

- Create a read/write view for W and a copy-on-write view for R.
- Use VirtualProtect to change the permissions on all pages of the read/write view to read-only.
- When a page fault is triggered, have the exception handler change the permission on the faulting page to read/write and make a dummy write to the corresponding page in the copy-on-write view.

I believe this approach to be the least efficient because I expect explicitly changing the permissions on a block would be significantly slower than using guard pages.  It may also result in more fragmentation of the page table.  However, if it turns out that it performs adequately, it would almost certainly be the most convenient solution.

---

*A few additional notes:*

I believe that all of these approaches should work, subject to the one caveat about what exactly happens when a second page fault is triggered while handling the first one.  I am not as confident about the comparative efficiency of the different variants.  It may be wise to do some comparison testing.

The file mapping object should probably be backed by the page file, and you may want to experiment with using large pages.  This would increase the amount of data that needed to be copied, but would reduce the load on the page table.  Again, comparison testing may be appropriate.

I assume you have already considered this, but future readers should note that depending on the nature of the data it might not be sensible to use mappings at all.  For example:

- Data blocks could be given two revision numbers, one indicating when the block becomes valid and the other when it should be considered deleted.  This approach would have very little time overhead, R just needs to check the revision numbers when processing a block so that it can skip blocks that are too new and delete blocks that are outdated.  This involves less data copying: W need only copy the data block it is working on, not entire pages, and adding/deleting blocks would not require any data to be copied at all.
- If the blocks need to be chained in a particular order, revision numbers might not be sufficient, but you could have separate chains for R and W.  Synchronization would require you to rechain the blocks, but that is still likely to be faster than modifying the page table.

Answer (score 0):

Even if someone will create the API you want, to do that CoW stuff.
Even if you’ll switch to separate processes instead of threads (there’s only 1 page table per process, you can’t have 2 threads see different data on same addresses).

If you’ll be modifying/remapping random 4kb pages, you gonna [waste gigabytes of RAM for your page table](https://serverfault.com/q/173606). Not only it wastes RAM but also degrades performance.

I feel the problem you see is too general, and you’re trying to solve it on the level of abstractions that’s too low.

How heavy is concurrency/performance requirements? Can you just lock your database, so that reading and writing never happen simultaneously?

What exactly is your view? Can you create the view at startup, when the new message arrives, update the DB on thread W, and update the view on thread R?

Is the whole thing persistent? If yes, just use an embedded NoSQL engine with transaction isolation feature. For example [ESENT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine), or if your software is cross-platform, [LMDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Memory-Mapped_Database) might fit.

Comment: Nothing needs to see different data on the same addresses; it's actually the opposite, I want to map the same data to different addresses. "Wasting gigabytes of RAM for the page table" is only true if large proportions of the dataset are different for different views, and the alternatives are even worse (double buffering means two entire copies of the dataset, locking the whole thing for every read and write essentially means serialising the reader and writer and why even bother putting them on separate threads if that's what you're doing? The idea is to decouple them!)

Comment: “Wasting gigabytes of RAM for the page table is only true if large proportions of the dataset are different for different views” — after many changes of your dataset, you’ll have continuous VMEM regions mapped to randomly-placed set of RAM pages. This takes two pages table entries (because your dataset is mapped to two VMEM places) per each page.

“double buffering means two entire copies of the dataset” — If you have 16GB dataset, you can’t have a 16 GB view. Even if you are working on a videogame where views can be extremely complex, VRAM is 2-4GB, so your view can’t be much larger than that

Comment: “locking the whole thing for every read and write essentially means serializing the reader and writer” — have you tried to implement locking? C++ critical sections/C# monitors are extremely efficient.

“why even bother putting them on separate threads” — because “receiving remote data, performing some work on it” will be done in a background thread, locking is only need for “publishing” changes. Moreover, you cam optimize: make the background thread don’t publish changes for a second, then publish them all in one lock.